# C# Google BigQuery SDK reference problems

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm trying to build a BigQuery application and I've hit a hurdle right out of the gate. (It's a .Net 4.6 console app)

I've installed the NuGet packages `Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2` (v1.3.0) and it installed a load of dependencies, one of which is System.Net.Http.

I modified the sample code from [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) to run a simple query against a test BigQuery DB.

When `BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectId);` is executed, I get a runtime **FileNotFoundException** telling me that `System.Net.Http 4.1.1.3 cannot be found` and the inner exception says `System.Net.Http 4.0.0.0 cannot be found`.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the **System.Net.Http** NuGet package several times, using different versions and I still get the same outcome. I've even just used the regular .Net 4.6 System.Net.Http dll and get the same issue.

If I change the **System.Net.Http** version to 4.0.0 via NuGet package manager, I get a different **FileNotFoundException** at the same point, but this time it says it can't find `Google.Api.Gax 2.7.0.0`, with the inner exception saying it can't find `Google.Api.Gax 2.5.0.0`. This same result happens with any version of `Google.Api.Gax`, except if I downgrade the `Google.Api.Gax` package to 2.5.0.0, I still get the runtime error saying `Google.Api.Gax 2.7.0.0` is missing, but this time with no inner exception mentioning `Google.Api.Gax 2.5.0.0`

What gives? I've had reference issues in the past, but never like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of trial and error with changing NuGet package versions, and with some minor successes, I eventually discovered that certain DLLs were not getting copied into the bin folder of my Unit Tests project, hence the runtime errors.

Each time I copied a DLL from the class library's bin folder to the Unit Test's bin folder, I'd get another missing DLL Exception for a different DLL. After copying them over one-by-one, it eventually ran.

Why would dependent DLLs not be copied into the bin folder of the project that references the class library?

i.e. Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 is installed in project A and project B references project A. The DLLs referenced in project A do not get copied to the bin folder of project B. (even though Copy Local is set to True!)

DLLs I had to copy manually:

- System.Net.Http.dll
- Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll (not
- System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
- System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
- Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2.dll (this is a particularly odd one because the NuGet package explicitly advises you to use Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 instead of Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2, but Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 depends on Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2)

As far as reference issues go, this one takes the cake. Maybe my copy of VS 2017 is to blame. Who knows...?